# Parsing a JSON array when its the first response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I am a bit stuck parsing a JSON array when it is the only thing returned in a JSON response.

I know how to parse an array when it is a sub record of a json response but not as the only response.

For example, i know how to do data.streams.array[0].item for example but when there is no 'streams' part of that i am not sure what to do (basically it goes straight to array[0]

Sample code of what i have tried below

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready to explore" );
$("#getMessage").click(function(){
$("ul").empty();
$.getJSON("https://api.planningalerts.org.au/applications.js?key=<<KEY>>&postcode=2000", function(json){
  var test2 = JSON.stringify(json);
  alert(test2);
  var test = json.address; 
  alert(test);
```

Sample json resposne i am trying to parse (remembering it goes straight to array)

```
[{
"application": {
    "id": 609706,
    "council_reference": "1-3879101556",
    "address": "\"Harbour Plaza\" Lot 5, 25-29 Dixon Street, Haymarket 2000",
    "description": "Triple 8 Hotel - Liquor licence transfer",
    "info_url": "http://www.ilga.nsw.gov.au/liquor/application-noticeboard",
    "comment_url": "mailto:liquorapplications@olgr.nsw.gov.au?subject=Application%20Number:%201-3879101556",
    "lat": -33.877797,
    "lng": 151.203659,
    "date_scraped": "2016-01-06T01:01:59.000Z",
    "date_received": "2016-01-05",
    "on_notice_from": null,
    "on_notice_to": "2016-02-04",
    "no_alerted": 178,
    "authority": {
        "full_name": "NSW Independent Liquor and Gaming Authority"
    }
}
}, {
"application": {
    "id": 609709,
    "council_reference": "1-3879170112",
    "address": "World Square L 10 680 George St, Sydney 2000",
    "description": "Sydney Chinese New Year 2016 - Chinese Film Festival 15/02/2016 - Limited licence - special event",
    "info_url": "http://www.ilga.nsw.gov.au/liquor/application-noticeboard",
    "comment_url": "mailto:liquorapplications@olgr.nsw.gov.au?subject=Application%20Number:%201-3879170112",
    "lat": -33.8772162,
    "lng": 151.2068193,
    "date_scraped": "2016-01-06T01:01:59.000Z",
    "date_received": "2016-01-05",
    "on_notice_from": null,
    "on_notice_to": "2016-01-19",
    "no_alerted": 182,
    "authority": {
        "full_name": "NSW Independent Liquor and Gaming Authority"
    }
}
}]
```

Any help really appreciated :)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't have to parse anything; jQuery will parse it before giving it to your callback. (For that reason, `json` probably isn't a great argument name; perhaps `data` or `response` or `applications`.)

To *access* its data, you do so just like any other JavaScript array (because that's what it is). For instance, the first entry is an object with a property called `application` which refers to an object with a property called `address` with the value `"\"Harbour Plaza\" Lot 5, 25-29 Dixon Street, Haymarket 2000"`. So:

```
console.log(json[0].application.address); // "Harbour Plaza" Lot 5, 25-29 Dixon Street, Haymarket 2000
```

There's also a second entry, whose address is `"World Square L 10 680 George St, Sydney 2000"`, so:

```
console.log(json[1].application.address); // World Square L 10 680 George St, Sydney 2000
```

Or [loop through the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476), for example:

```
json.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry.application.address);
});
```

shows

```
"Harbour Plaza" Lot 5, 25-29 Dixon Street, Haymarket 2000
World Square L 10 680 George St, Sydney 2000
```

Comment: Thanks very much :) I was familiar with Jquery etc but i was confused by the fact it returned the array only and not as a subset.